# How to query multiple inherited sub-classes in a single query in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, inheritance, oftype

I have a big problem of querying diverse types of inherited subentities in a single query in Entity Framework. My essential aim is providing all of my data model structure in a single JSON string by eager loading. And the tricky point is "the inherited subclasses may contain another inherited subclass". The example seen below will clearly explain the situation.

Assume that I have a simple class structure like this:

```
public class Teacher
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string fullname{ get; set; }
        //navigation properties
        public virtual HashSet<Course> courses{ get; set; }
    }

public class Course
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string coursename{ get; set; }
        //foreign keys
        public int TeacherId{ get; set; }
        //navigation properties
        public virtual Teacher teacher{ get; set; }
        public virtual HashSet<Course> prerequisites{ get; set; }
    }
```

**Course has some subclasses GradedCourse and UngradedCourse**
**B1 or B2 may have a list of subentities consists of entities of types B1 or B2.**

```
public class GradedCourse : Course
    {
        public string gradeType{ get; set; }
    }

public class UngradedCourse: Course
    {
        public string successMetric { get; set; }
    }
```

**Now by this structure I want to provide a JSON structure from my WEBApi yielding list of Teacher objects including both GradedCourse and UngradedCourse with their subentities and specific fields. I have a query like this but it does not compile**

```
db.Teachers.Select(t => new 
  { 
  t.id,
  t.fullName
  courses = t.courses.OfType<GradedCourses>()
            .Select(g => new
              {
                id = g.id,
                coursename = g.coursename,
                prerequisites = g.prerequisites, // this is the list of other subentities 
                gradeType = g.gradeType 
              }
             ).Concat(t.courses.OfType<UngradedCourses>()
                       .Select(u => new
                         {
                          id = u.id,
                          coursename = u.coursename,
                          prerequisites = g.prerequisites, // this is the list of other subentities 
                          successMetric= u.successMetric // subclass specific field
                         }
                        )
               )
  } 
)
```

The problem is concating two different types of objects (they have different fields which is not possible for SQL UNION)

How can I handle this? Any help will open my mind. Thanks in advance for the professionals :)

Answer (score 0):

It does not compile because the element type of 2 sets is not the same. So you just need to make them the same before being able to do anything:

```
db.Teachers.Select(t => new 
{ 
 t.id,
 t.fullName
 courses = t.courses.OfType<GradedCourses>()
            .Select(g => new
            {
              id = g.id,
              coursename = g.coursename,
              prerequisites = g.prerequisites, // this is the list of other subentities 
              isGradedCourse = true,
              gradeTypeOrMetric = g.gradeType 
            }).Concat(t.courses.OfType<UngradedCourses>()
              .Select(u => new
                     {
                      id = u.id,
                      coursename = u.coursename,
                      prerequisites = g.prerequisites, // this is the list of other subentities 
                      isGradedCourse = false,
                      gradeTypeOrMetric= u.successMetric // subclass specific field
                     }))
              //finally select what of your choice
              .Select(e => new {
                  id = e.id,
                  coursename = e.coursename,
                  prerequisites = e.prerequisites,
                  gradeType = e.isGradedCourse ? e.gradeTypeOrMetric : "",
                  successMetric = e.isGradedCourse ? "" : e.gradeTypeOrMetric
              })
});
```

You still benefit the query being executed on server side without having to pull all teachers to local (and then being able to cast the entities - which is not supported in LinqToEntity query).